Is there a way to import multiple layers to PostgreSQL via QGIS at the same time?
I have created a QGIS project with numerous layers for testing purposes. These layers are all saved in a geopackage.
I would like to import all the layers individually into a PostgreSQL database as well. Unfortunately, the database manager in QGIS only works layer by layer, but I need to import all layers at the same time.
Is there a way to load several layers into the PostgreSQL database in QGIS at the same time?

AFAIK you can't do that using QGIS but using GDAL you can:
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL "PG:user=youruser password=yourpassword dbname=yourdbname" yourgeopackage.gpkg

By default it will "clean" your column names etc, add -lco LAUNDER=NO if you prefer to aggravation of upper case names.

Thanks for your answer!
Another way, as I found out, is to run a batch process via the tool "Database" -> "Export to PostgreSQL". This allows you to select all the desired layers and write them to the database in batches.
